# What causes a function to "freeze" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Say in window.onload function i call a bunch of other methods:

```
function window.onload(){
 method1();
 alert("test1");
 method2();
 alert("test2");
}
```

So my test1 method is working fine, i get the alert "test1", but then it appears that my code is "freezing" on method2, so the alert "test2" is not being called.

Here is what my test2 method looks like

```
function method2(){
alert("testing");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "url that i want to call from", true);

xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status==200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert("yay");
            }
            else{
                alert("Aww");
            }
}

xhr.send();
```

}

what i dont understand is why i dont even get the alert "testing", if my code is freezing somewhere why doesnt it at least run the first line in the method?

Can anyone explain why this occurs in javascript?

thanks

Comment: Do you hit OK on alert test1?

Comment: yes, from what ive tested it just seems like the code freezes as soon as method2 is called

Answer (score 0):

I have always hooked into to the 'on ready state change' event.

```
<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadDoc();
    });
    function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                alert("yay");
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "demo", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

From the information you provided, I am guessing that you are running into browser security issues ...

I would recommend using jquery to handle the job for you.  the $(document).ready function in jquery has always worked awesomely for me in the years I have been using the framework.

If you can't use jquery, then you need to have the user click on a button in order to initiate the http request you desire.

Also, if you need to perform the 'Awww' action you can append it to the if statement but I would recommend using if else based on xhttp.readyState values or your 'Awww' will repeat often.